# Can Amazon EBS run on it's own or does it need to be attached to an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Can EBS run on it's own or does it need to be attached to an instance?

I'm confused by the whole thing.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) provides block level storage volumes for use with EC2 instances.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html

EBS provides the hard drives for EC2 instances.  An EBS volume doesn't "run."  A volume that isn't attached to an EC2 instance can't be used for anything, except that it's possible to take a backup snapshot of a volume that doesn't happen to be attached to an instance at the moment.  Snapshots can then be used to create more identical EBS volumes (same contents as the original), of the same size or larger.

But EBS is a storage service that works exclusively with EC2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clears things up.  So I'm assuming my data is stored on the EBS hard disk attached to the EC2 instance and not an Instance Store (provides temporary block-level storage for your instance)?

Comment: Also, I'm slightly concerned that the EC2 billing cost on my conservative website is at $1 after a single day.

Comment: You have to make some effort to use the instance store volumes on an EBS-backed instance, so you are probably not going to use it inadvertently. The t2 instance class is the lowest cost class, and does not offer instance store volumes at all.  What did you provision as far as instance class and EBS volume size? If your web site is simple and static, of course, you can host the whole thing on S3.

Comment: Thanks again for the response - that once again helps clear things up. My site is written in PHP and is database driven so needs an EC2 instance.  I opted for the free tier option when signing up to AWS with 30 GB of EBS space (not that I will ever need this much) so am clueless to why I'm being charged.  Anyhow, got to make sure that costs don't spiral out of control as cheaper shared hosting may be the way forward if they do.

Comment: The free tier is really free, if you use only the services it includes.  If you are seeing charges, there **is** an explanation, and you should try to understand what that is.  If you chose an instance type that isn't free, or inadvertently launched more than once instance, for example.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/tracking-free-tier-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create EBS volumes separately from instances and attache/deattache them to running instances.